# Добавление элементов в динамический массив

Tags: массивы, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста! Почему не вводит с клавиатуры значения в массив?

```
   struct DynamicArray{
    int cols, rows;
    double ** array_;
};
void dynamic_memory(DynamicArray &Arrays)
{
    Arrays.array_ = (double **) malloc(Arrays.rows*sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < Arrays.rows; i++)
        Arrays.array_[i] = (double *) malloc(Arrays.cols * sizeof(double));
}

void FillDynamicArray(DynamicArray &Arrays)
{   printf("Введите свободные члены(0 для целевой функции) \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Arrays.rows+ Arrays.cols+2; i++)
        scanf("%lf", &Arrays.array_[i][0]);
    printf("Введите коэффициенты (построчно, через пробел) \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < Arrays.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Arrays.cols+1; j++)
        {
                scanf("%lf", &Arrays.array_[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void PrintArray(DynamicArray &Arrays)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Arrays.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Arrays.cols; j++)
        {
            printf("%lf ", Arrays.array_[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int _tmain(void)
{
    int n; 
    DynamicArray A;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    FillDynamicArray(A);
    PrintArray(A);
    FreeDynamicMemory(A);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что в вашем случае DynamicArray? Приведите описание класса, в частности, что есть Arrays.array_[i][j]? Если array_ - это действительно массив, т.е. int**, то не хватает "&", т.к. в функцию scanf надо передавать указатель.

Comment: @Кюри, опишите толком, что происходит (что Вы **видите на экране**).

Вряд ли это текст: 

        "не хочу вводить данные..."

А также, приведите код, вызывающий `FillDynamicArray()` и код, инициализирующий struct, передаваемую в `FillDynamicArray()`.

Тогда, (может быть) какая-то добрая душа....

Comment: @Кюри, у Вас структура, передаваемая в `FillDynamicArray()` не инициализирована. Не установлены `A.cols`, `A.rows` и не выделена память в `A.array_` (*это делает функция `dynamic_memory()`*).

Поэтому (**память не выделена**) и падает.

Comment: @avp, а Вы не могли бы мне этот кусочек написать! Пожалуйста! Если, конечно, не сложно...

Comment: Неужели не получается?

    int _tmain(void)
    {
      int n; 
      DynamicArray A;
      setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

      cout << "Enter cols & rows: ";
      if (!(cin >> A.cols >> A.rows)) {
        cout << "Input error. Bye!\n";
        return 1;
      }
      dynamic_memory(A);

      FillDynamicArray(A);
      PrintArray(A);
      FreeDynamicMemory(A);
      _getch();
      return 0;
    }

Comment: У меня очень тяжело с динамической памятью!((
переделала, но теперь он выдает ошибку в последней строчке этой функции!
{
void dynamic_memory(DynamicArray &Arrays)
{
    Arrays.array_ = (double **) malloc(Arrays.rows*sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < Arrays.rows; i++)
        Arrays.array_[i] = (double *) malloc(Arrays.cols * sizeof(double));
} }

Comment: @Кюри, из Вас информацию просто клещами, что ли, тащить надо?

`dynamic_memory()` при нормальных аргументах должна работать правильно.
`A.rows` и `A.cols` чему  у Вас равны???

Вставьте отладочную печать на входе в функции.

А вот границы циклов в `FillDynamicArray()` явно не согласованные (превышают значения cols и rows, что приведет к ошибке).


Скорее всего Вы хотите сначала заполнить 0-й столбец, а потом во вложенных циклах остальную часть всех строк матрицы. Тогда цикл по i до rows, а во вложенном цикле j меняйте от 1 до cols.

--

(все. у меня комментарии закончились...)

Comment: @avp, спасибо за помощь!)
я согласовала границы циклов, и все равно он останавливается на выделении динамической памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Кюри](/users/18799/%D0%BA%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8), я прям и не знаю, в чем у Вас проблема.

Минимально подправил (границы в `FillDynammicArray()` и виндозные заморочки) Ваш код

```
void FillDynamicArray(DynamicArray &Arrays)
{   
  printf("Введите свободные члены(0 для целевой функции) \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < Arrays.rows; i++)
    scanf("%lf", &Arrays.array_[i][0]);
  printf("Введите коэффициенты (построчно, через пробел) \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < Arrays.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < Arrays.cols; j++) {
      scanf("%lf", &Arrays.array_[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

int main () {

  int n; 
  DynamicArray A;
  //    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

  cout << "Enter cols & rows: "; 
  if (!(cin >> A.cols >> A.rows)) {
    cout << "Input error. Bye!\n";
    return 1;
  }

  cout << A.cols << " x " << A.rows << '\n';

  dynamic_memory(A);
  FillDynamicArray(A);
  PrintArray(A);
    //    FreeDynamicMemory(A);
    //    _getch();
  return 0;
}

avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ c.cpp
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
Enter cols & rows: 3 2
3 x 2
Введите свободные члены(0 для целевой функции) 
1
2
Введите коэффициенты (построчно, через пробел) 
3 4
5 6
1.000000 3.000000 4.000000 
2.000000 5.000000 6.000000 
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

И все вроде работает.

Comment: спасибо за лабу =)))

Comment: @Gorets, да не жалко. 

Вы же не считаете, что реально девушке грозит стать программером?

Comment: @avp, ну что Вы! Девушки ж поступают на программистов только, чтобы мужа найти))
Спасибо за ответ!
Все, что давали на лекциях оказалось неправильным...

Comment: @Кюри, не обижайтесь. Все у Вас получиться (ник-то какой!) 

(если, конечно, будете ежедневно тренироваться и читать много книжек).

Comment: @avp,  я не обижаюсь совсем! Я прекрасно понимаю, что в программировании почти ноль. Хотя в последнюю неделю мне уже ночами код этой программы снится!!! Вот надо снова спрашивать, массив грузится, а основное задание не работает(((
Ник-да, хорош) Восхищаюсь этим семейством и Марией, в частности.